# ASP.NET Core: Mark [FromQuery] Parameter as required

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, query-string

In my controller there is a method take accepts one route and and one query parameter as arguments:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// My Method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="routeParameter">Nice description of route parameter.</param>
/// <param name="queryParameter">Nice description of query paramter.</param>
[HttpPost("somePath/{routeParameter}")]
public IActionResult MyMethod([FromRoute] string routeParameter, [FromQuery] DateTime queryParamter)
{
   // do something 
}
```

In the OpenApi.json / Swagger generated from this signature via Swashbuckle XML the `routeParameter` (path) is always required but the  `queryParameter` (query) is marked as optional.

**How can I mark the query parameter as required, too?**

Comment: This is basically the opposite of this question where route parameters should be optional: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342079/how-to-mark-api-parameter-as-optional-for-swagger-ui-for-web-api-2

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem? If it is solved, please accept it as the answer, otherwise, please tell me your still existing problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I mark the query parameter as required, too?

Just use **[FromQuery, BindRequired]** as follow:

```cs
[HttpPost("somePath/{routeParameter}")]
public IActionResult MyMethod([FromRoute] string routeParameter, [FromQuery, BindRequired] DateTime queryParamter)
{
    // do something  
}
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: `[BindRequired]` was enough for me

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative with `[FromUri]` to receive your parameters

```
[HttpPost("somePath")]
public IActionResult MyMethod([FromUri] Paging paging, [FromUri] QueryParam param)
{
   // do something 
}
```

QueryParam.cs

```
public class QueryParam
{
    [Required]
    public string routeParameter{ get; set; }
}
```

**Swagger UI**

[image]